# Including header files in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2012

I want to include one header file in other and then to include the second header file in .c file.
I want to define a constant in first header file and use its value in c file.
I think this is possible because it is done in standart libraries

When I do this compiler is sending an error message:

> 1>C:\Users\sotfware\Desktop\ConsoleApplication4\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's OK. Maybe you can show more details about your problem.

---

First header (a.h):

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

const int i = 5;

#endif
```

---

Second header (b.h):

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

#endif
```

---

source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.h"

main() {
  printf("%d\n", i);
  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the definitions (body) of the functions in a regular C file and only the declarations in the header files. Let's say I have these functions:

```
void PrintHelloWorld(void)
{
      printf("Hello World\n");
}

void PrintHelloWorld2(void)
{
      printf("Hello World");
}
```

Then my C file would stay this ^^ but the Header file should be:

```
void PrintHelloWorld();
void PrintHelloWorld2();
```

As I remember, I think you should declare the constant in the header file.